# In JPA, how do I map a table to an entity which is a composite?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Sometimes you have a huge entity with numerous fields and it would be nice to split up the entity into separate classes to handle the complexity.

Say I have a table Foo with columns

```
someStuff, aThingBlah, aThingEtc, bThingWhatever, bThingBacon
```

and this class (annotations left out)

```
class Foo {
  String someStuff;
  String aThingBlah;
  String aThingEtc;
  String bThingWhatever;
  String bThingBacon;
}
```

I'd like to refactor this (without changing the db table) to

```
class Foo {
  String someStuff;
  AThing aThing;
  BThing bThing;
}
class AThing {
  String blah;
  String etc;
}
class BThing {
  String whatever;
  String bacon;
}
```

Is it possible to do this and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basics...

```
class Foo {

  String someStuff;

  @Embedded
  @AttributeOverrides({
     @AttributeOverride( name = "blah", column = @Column(name="aThingBlah") ),
     ...
  })
  AThing aThing;

};

@Embeddable
class AThing {

  @Column(...)
  String blah;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible. which one holds the id?  sounds like they would all share the same id and because of that hibernate would not know how to load or save any of these. (without some sort of discriminator)

also If i were to save a *BThing* then what would happen to the fields defined in *Foo*,*Athing*?  They would be totally out of hibernates scope.

Comment: You can't save a BThing - there's only one table which contains all the fields. Foo is a composite, not an aggregate - ie a BThing should only exist as part of a Foo - it shouldn't exist by itself.